# Download apc for php 5.5.3

Tags: php, xampp, apc, php-5.5

I have XAMPP 1.8.3 [PHP: 5.5.3]. I need APC for this php version. From where can i download it. I found [php_apc-3.1.10-5.4-vc9-x86.zip](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_apc-3.1.10-5.4-vc9-x86.zip) here but it is not working for me.
I am using windows 7

Comment: PHP 5.5 no longer needs APC. It has an integrated opcode cache (search "php opcache"). If you need the APC user cache, use the apcu extension.

Comment: where to find apcu extension ?